# script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ deleted but still runs

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend, systemd, wakeup

I wrote a script to be run after suspend, (script was in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ directory) but after a test I decided to delete it from there, but the script is still running - I know it because script had notify-send in it, and now every time I wake up my laptop I see notifications popping up. How is that possible and how can I completely remove it ?

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

after removing the script.

After testing this myself it turns out that a daemon-reload is not enough. Even `systemctl daemon-reexec` doesn't help. So the only way to get rid of the running script seems to be a reboot or killing the process manually.

Explanation why this is possible: It is normal on Linux that you can delete a script while it's running. What really happens is that the directory entry is removed (the file becomes "invisible"), but it is really gone only after all processes have closed the open file handles for this file.

You can test this behaviour like this:

```
$ printf "#!/bin/sh\nsleep 10000" >/tmp/bla
$ chmod +x /tmp/bla
$ /tmp/bla &; rm /tmp/bla
[1] 5959
$ ls -l /tmp/bla
ls: cannot access '/tmp/bla': No such file or directory
```

You will see that the script is gone, but still running until you kill its process.

Comment: Thanks, I tried reboot before I asked here, but reboot didn't help. So I tried your commands and I still get notification after wake up.  It's getting pretty annoying now

Comment: You must have a copy of the script under another path. After a reboot and after deleting the file I believe it would be impossible that it's not gone.

Comment: yes, what happened is that I had one script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ to enable/disable WIFI based on wired connection state. Then I wrote another script that checks wired connection state after wake up and put it in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/  directory. Funny thing is, that now script from dispatcher.d directory runs after wake up, no idea why